# Why does OleDbDataAdapter leave artifacts when filling a DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datatable, oledb

I wrote some methods which are supposed to fetch a DataTable for each WorkSheet in a Excel file:

**Step 1** is to get the names of all sheets included in a .xlsx file:

```
private static List<string> GetSheetNames(string filePath) 
        {
            List<string> sheetNames = new List<string>();
            DataTable dt = null;

            try 
            {
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + filePath + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'");
                connection.Open();
                dt = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                if (dt == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                // Add the sheet name to the string array.
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    sheetNames.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());

                }

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            return sheetNames;
        }
```

**Step 2** is to read every sheet and return an according `DataTable`:

```
private static DataTable ReadExcelSheet(string filePath,string sheetName)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    ValidateSheetName(ref sheetName);
    try
    {                
        OleDbConnection connection;
        DataSet DtSet;
        OleDbDataAdapter cmd;
        connection = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + filePath + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'");
        cmd = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from ["+sheetName+"]", connection);
        cmd.TableMappings.Add("Table", sheetName.Replace("$",string.Empty));
        DtSet = new DataSet();
        cmd.Fill(DtSet);
        table = DtSet.Tables[0];
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    return table;
}
```

Both methods are called from this last method which returns a `List<DataTable>`:

```
private static List<DataTable> ConvertExcelToTables(string filePath) 
{
    List<string> sheetNames = GetSheetNames(filePath);
    List<DataTable> tableList = new List<DataTable>();

    foreach(string sheetName in sheetNames)
    {
        tableList.Add(ReadExcelSheet(filePath,sheetName));
    }

    return tableList;
}
```

There is also a little helper method which should be irrelevant for the question:

```
private static void ValidateSheetName(ref string sheetName)
{
   sheetName = sheetName.EndsWith("$") ? sheetName : sheetName + "$";
}
```

If I take one sheet from a example file it looks like this:

[image]

Now no matter if I just look into the `DataTable` while debugging or if I bind it as a `DataSource` of a `DataGridView` the result looks a little weird:

[image]

My guess is that this might have to do with Excel sheets beginning counting with 1 not with 0. But even if this is the case I can't really think of a solution. Or did I miss something. Actually this is a pity because this seems to be a clean solution imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the problem is caused by

```
HDR=YES;
```

in your connection string.
Change it to

```
HDR=NO;
```

`HDR=YES` means that the first line of your Excel sheets is assumed to contain the fields' names of your table. But this is not the case with the sheet shown as an example. Indeed the OleDb provider cannot determine the name of the second column (it's blank) and thus it assigns the default value (the letter `F` followed by the progressive number of the column)

You could find a lot of examples and explanations about connectionstrings for excel at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Comment: This did solve the problem. Maybe you want provide a little information on what this parameter actually stands for? Btw the column headings are still named F1,F2..which is not a big deal but still not perfect ^^

Comment: Not really worth another post. In case all cells are empty and the first cell containing information is B7 it will be in Cell(0,0) in my datatable. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Normally no, your sheet is a table that extends from A1 to the last valid row/cell. With all the empty rows and columns. Unless you define a range on the Excel Sheet and then use the SELECT * from [RangeName] syntax in your OleDb command